# How can I fix the problem which occur during flutter config --android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio5"
Setting "android-studio-dir" value to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio5".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

[image: Screenshot from the console]

Answer (score 0):

***Solution One***

If you're using Android Studio , you can configure your platform SDK by going to File

-> Project structure and choose your platform SDK.

[image]

***Solution Two***

For Windows: Inside Android Studio, get path from : Apprearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK > Android SDK path

Make sure your path does not contain any spaces in them, if you have edit path and re-install sdk to a different location.
After that,

```
flutter config --android-sdk {path} 
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

You are set!